# Netplan issues with Hetzner and ip's

Tags: 22.04, virtualization, netplan

I have the following config on 01-netplan.conf think it's called.

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: no
  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces: [eno1]
      addresses:
        - IP/32
      routes:
        - on-link: true
          to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: Gateway
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 1.1.1.1
          - 1.0.0.1
```

It's via over at Hetzner.

But when i wrote netplan apply it lost connection. How would i go about diagnosing this?

Comment: Just a extra bunch of information:

Route seems okay:
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1122552169430798559/1207589751042080808/image.png?ex=65e03298&is=65cdbd98&hm=179fd0d5a9197600043a97e0374c20ebea129170a65fac394eb0cc74442155dd&

Comment: And the startup log for netplan seems okay aswell

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1122552169430798559/1207590357840297984/image.png?ex=65e03329&is=65cdbe29&hm=c5b302cea5621ef595b911543c0aa2fcb4eb4e1f309e32038133a3277feb2f80&

Comment: Did you try requesting a virtual MAC, as described here? https://docs.hetzner.com/robot/dedicated-server/network/net-config-debian-ubuntu/#bridged